# How to write a foreach that will produce the results I want

Tags: php

I am having a hard time getting the correct data out of an array. I wrote a nested foreach loop but the inner loop is throwing the "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error. Can someone please help me out with this? Thanks.

```
foreach($row as $val)
{
    echo $val['title'].'<br>';
    echo $val['author'].'<br>';
    echo $val['post'].'<br>';
    echo $val['entry_date'].'<br>';
    echo $val['comments'].'<br>';

    foreach($val as $val2)
    {
        echo $val['comments'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

---

```
Array
(
    [title] => First Blog
    [author] => Administrator
    [post] => Testing entry number one
    [entry_date] => Fri, 23 Oct 2009
    [comments] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [commenter] => Sally Anderson
                    [comments] => comment 1 post 1
                    [comment_date] => October 24th, 2009 at 5:24 AM
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [commenter] => Mike Jones
                    [comments] => comment 2 post 1
                    [comment_date] => October 24th, 2009 at 5:21 AM
                )
        )
)
Array
(
    [title] => Second Blog
    [author] => Administrator
    [post] => Testing entry number two
    [entry_date] => Sat, 24 Oct 2009
    [comments] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [commenter] => Sally Anderson
                    [comments] => comment 1 post 2
                    [comment_date] => October 24th, 2009 at 5:21 AM
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [commenter] => Mike Jones
                    [comments] => comment 2 post 2
                    [comment_date] => October 24th, 2009 at 5:21 AM
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `$rows` is the structure at the bottom of your question (an array of arrays) then:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  echo <<<END
$row[title]<br>
$row[author]<br>
$row[post]<br>
$row[entry_date]<br>
END;
  foreach ($row['comments'] as $comment) {
    echo <<<END
$comment[comments]<br>
$comment[commentor]<br>
$comment[comment_date]<br>
END;
  }
}
```

I strongly suggest you choose meaningful names (like `$comment` and `$row`) rather than meaningless names like `$val` and `$val2` as these are just going to cause confusion.

Also I've used [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) in the revised version as I tend to think that can make things much more readable but that's optional. A better alternative might be:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
<?php echo $row['title'] ?><br>
<?php echo $row['post'] ?><br>
<?php echo $row['entry_date'] ?><br>
<?php foreach ($row['comments'] as $comment): ?>
<?php echo $comment['comments'] ?><br>
<?php echo $comment['commentor'] ?><br>
<?php echo $comment['comment_date'] ?><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

which can be useful if you've got a lot of HTML interspersed. The above switched to using [alternative control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), which is optional but is often considered more readable in this type of code.

Lastly, you could [PHP short tags](http://www.bin-co.com/php/articles/using_php_short_tags.php), which some people don't like (either because they might be disabled or they interface with XML processing instructions) but I generally prefer:

```
<? foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
<?= $row['title'] ?><br>
<?= $row['post'] ?><br>
<?= $row['entry_date'] ?><br>
<? foreach ($row['comments'] as $comment): ?>
<?= $comment['comments'] ?><br>
<?= $comment['commentor'] ?><br>
<?= $comment['comment_date'] ?><br>
<? endforeach; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Cletus, Thanks for the help. I tried this but I am still getting the error. I'm getting the value echo but the errors are still appearing in my log. Any ideas?

Comment: Cletus, thank you. Your solution works but I have no idea why... Thanks. I will look into the heredoc syntax as well.

Comment: @jack - spell out the foreach.... foreach (item in) $collection (as) $singular (do) etc.  When you got to the nested array, you tried to treat it as a singular, whereas it's another collection!  That collection ($row[comments] in your case) needs to be passed to the nested loop; foreach (item in) $comments_collection (as) $comment (do)....

Comment: Hi dsclose, thanks for the explanation. It really puts it into prospective for me. Also, I'm embarrassed to admit this, but I didn't realize that I could have referred to a "collection" in a foreach like $row['comments']. This helps me greatly. Thank you al again for the great help.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
foreach($val as $val2)
{
    echo $val['comments'].'<br>';
}
```

to

```
foreach($val['comments'] as $val2)
{
    echo $val2['comments'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I tried this but I am still getting: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() as well as undefined index. Would you know why